# Application of AC optocoupler

Tags: opto-isolator, optoelectronics

I found this circuit for an AC optocoupler:

[image]

For this circuit, what would be the criteria to choose the correct resistors and capacitors?

Why were these values chosen?

How do I select the right values for a certain application?

Comment: "The" resistor makes no sense, since you have four of them.

Comment: @Olin - I think the OP means resistors and capacitor.

Comment: @Rica: Exactly, you *think* he means...  Of course we can make various guesses, and that's one of them, but the question as it stands now makes no sense.

Comment: Where did you get this circuit? Probably they explained why they chose these values there. If not, what is you exact application?

Answer (score 1):

When you have signal at the R85 input generaly is PWM the transistor at OK2 is conductive and the capacitor C12 is charged through R32 and 3.3V when the capacitor is charged the transistor T5 switch from blocked to condictive and when the capacitor is discharged through R83 the transistor T5 is blocked. The resistors R32 and R85 are used to define the charge and discharge time where the resitor R33 and R85 are used to limite the input current.